# Create Phone type column from the source of phone numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `account` and `customer`:

```
Create Table Account
(
      PrimaryRowId varchar(12),
      SecondaryRowId varchar (12),
      AccountNumber varchar(50)
);

Create table Customer
(
    CustomerRowId varchar(12),
    MobilePhone varchar(20),
    HomePhone Varchar(20),
    CellPhone Varchar(20)
);
```

What I would like to see is an output that shows the account, the phonenumber, and the phonenumbertype. This PhoneNumberType will be based off of where my numbers come from. So if they come from mobilePhone column I would like to have mobile for the phonenumbertype. I already have a way a getting the primary and secondary accounts and their phoneNumbers. I would now like to give them a phonetype, so mobile would get mobile, home would get personal, work would get work and so on. Is there a way I can accomplish this by basing it off of where the number comes from(Mobilephone, HomePhone, cellPhone). So say I have a mobile number 8773409646 and that number comes from mobile. I would like to see the accountnumber, phonenumber, and beside the phoneNumber in another field named phonetype I would like to give it mobile.

Expected Results:

```
AccountNumber   PhoneNumber   PhoneType
-----------------------------------------
  34567434       8773409646     Mobile
```

Comment: Please include sample data and the corresponding expected result with your attempt

Comment: What if the customer has multiple phone numbers?

Comment: Are `PrimaryRowId` and `SecondaryRowId` foreign keys into the `Customer` table?

Comment: @Nick that is totally fine It will just create another row for a different phoneNumber is how my process works. I just want to be able to give it a type.

Comment: @Nick Those join on the customerrowid in the customertable for the correct account

Comment: Is it possible for you to refactor the Customer table to list all phone numbers in one columns, and create another column with a flag to indicate the phone type?

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the `Accounts` table to a list of all the phone numbers and their types in the `Customer` table, which you can create with a `UNION ALL` query:

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, c.PhoneNumber, c.PhoneType
FROM Account a
JOIN (SELECT CustomerRowId, MobilePhone AS PhoneNumber, 'Mobile' AS PhoneType
      FROM Customer
      WHERE MobilePhone != ''
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CustomerRowId, HomePhone, 'Home'
      FROM Customer
      WHERE HomePhone != ''
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CustomerRowId, CellPhone, 'Cell'
      FROM Customer
      WHERE CellPhone != '') c ON c.CustomerRowId IN (a.PrimaryRowId, a.SecondaryRowId)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=146f44516fb3cc5005591d1d975167bf)

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT 
 A.AccountNumber,
 CASE
  WHEN B.MobilePhone <> '' THEN B.MobilePhone 
  WHEN B.HomePhone <> '' THEN B.HomePhone
  WHEN B.CellPhone <> '' THEN B.CellPhone
 END AS PhoneNumber ,
 CASE
  WHEN B.MobilePhone <> '' THEN 'MobilePhone'
  WHEN B.HomePhone <> '' THEN 'HomePhone'
  WHEN B.CellPhone <> '' THEN 'CellPhone'
 END AS PhoneType
FROM Account A
 JOIN Customer B ON
 A.PrimaryRowId = B.CustomerRowId
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows you to unpivot values using `APPLY`.  This is very handy in this case:

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, v.PhoneNumber, v.PhoneType
FROM Account a JOIN
     Customer c
     ON c.CustomerRowId IN (a.PrimaryRowId, a.SecondaryRowId) CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Mobile', MobilePhone),
             ('Home', HomePhone),
             ('Cell', CellPhone)
     ) v(PhoneType, PhoneNumber)
WHERE v.PhoneNumber IS NOT NULL;
```